# Styling a Separator Nav with round edges stricly in CSS

Tags: css

My navbar looks like:

```
   <div id="navbar">
        <ul class="tabnavcenter">
          <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Test</a></li>
          <li class="aaron"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
   </div>
```

And my CSS for the NavBar looks like:

```
ul.tabnavcenter    {

    background: #fff;
    padding:0px 0px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:957px;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #cacaca, #848484);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#cacaca), to(#848484));
                         }
  ul.tabnavcenter li {
    float:left;
    border-right: #DDDDDD 1px solid;
     list-style-type:none;
                }

    ul.tabnavcenter li.active  {
       background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #cacaca, #4B4B4B);
       background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#cacaca), to(#4B4B4B));

            }


   ul.tabnavcenter li:hover {
       background: #7D7D7D;
       cursor:pointer;
                            }
```

Is there a possible way I could add rounded edges to the first and last link just using CSS? :)

Comment: Don't forget the other browsers when you're doing gradients: http://css3please.com/#box_gradient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put your code into a JS Fiddle but it's not apparent how you want to handle the last link (because of the gradient to the right, a rounded edge would look strange).

http://jsfiddle.net/Kk7vK/

> Is there a possible way I could add rounded edges to the first and
>   last link just using CSS?

First/last can be selected using `:first-child` and `:last-child`. Browser support is good (IE7+) for `first-child`, not so good (IE9+) on `last-child`.

**Example**

```
ul.tabnavcenter > LI:first-child{ /* do something different */ }
```

CSS Selector Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/

Rounded edges can be achieved using `border-radius` (with vendor-specific prefix(es) such as `-moz-border-radius`). Internet Explorer support for `border-radius` started with IE9 (though there are [polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills) for < IE9).

Comment: Tim, is this correct?   ul.tabnavcenter li:first-child  {
     /* Rounded Corners */
     -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
     -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
     -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

Comment: Here's a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/Kk7vK/1/. Because the gradient is applied on the container element, you need to apply the border-radius there (instead of on the LI). You can do without the first-child selector in this case.

Comment: Thanks Tim!!! btw, you wouldn't happen to know a prettier/better way to display small whitespace in between the links would you? :P

Comment: No problem. The way you are using a border is fine for spacing between the links, unless you wanted a different effect?